# How to connect Rails with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following running correctly:

1. `rails new simple`
2. `rails server` (working)
3. `rails generate controller demo index`
4. `mysql -u root -p` and creating the database and assigning GRANT PRIVILIGES on the database is done.

Now the problem is, I used the Bitnami-RubyStack packages on my MAC 10.7. When I want to run `rake db:schema:dump`, I get this error:

```
bash-3.2$ rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-18/simple/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

even if I run GRANT PRIVILEGES.

Also I checked the username and password on my DB.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: something
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: can you access via terminal via `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: It seems your mysql username or password is wrong...try to login using terminal command mysql -u Username -p Password..

Answer (score 0):

In your database config

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: something
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

you should use either socket or host, not both. Since socket works for you (`mysql -u root -p` works), try using it with your app. If there's any permission problems or whatnot, you are going to have to create `root@127.0.0.1` in your `mysql` console and use the host parameter.

Comment: I found the answer after spending a lot of time. I kept both socket and host in my db.yml file. but i changed my host name it worked now. thanks a lot